# How to find the Sum of digits recursively

Tags: bash, shell

I need to find the sum of digits in shell recursively. but I've a mistake:
line 10: 5 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")

```
function countofnumbers
{
    if [ $1 -lt 10 ]
    then
        return $1
    else
        let z=$1/10
        let result=expr`$(($(( $1 % 10 )) + $(countofnumbers $z)))`
    fi
    return $result
}
z=15
echo $(countofnumbers $z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, nice job!

```
function countofnumbers {
    if [ $1 -lt 10 ]
    then
        echo $1
    else
        z=$(( $1 / 10 ))
        result=$(( $(( $1 % 10 )) + $(countofnumbers $z) ))
    fi
    echo $result
}
```

Here's the changes I made:

> `z=$(( $1 / 10 ))`

Every time you do math in bash, wrap it in the arithmetic operators `$(( ))`. While `let` works as well, you appear to be combining all 3 styles (`expr`, `let`, `$(( ))`) more or less at random. Your code will be more readable if you stick to one style.

> `result=$(( $(( $1 % 10 )) + $(count $z) ))`

You just had too many things around this one. The arithmetic operators alone are enough. `expr` is an alternate form of the arithmetic operator, but we didn't need it here.

> `return $1`
>   `return $result`

Bash doesn't do `return` like any other programming language. Return refers to the return code, which is a number 0-255, and is mainly used for expressing whether or not an error occurred. The results are captured just as you thought though, e.g.,

```
mynum=$(countofnumbers 12)
echo $mynum
> 3
```

Comment: Note that `z=$(( $1 / 10 ))` is actually the same as `let z=$1/10`. (You say "Every time you do math in bash, wrap it in the arithmetic operators `$(( ))`", which is not bad advice, but is not strictly necessary.)

Comment: I will make it clear that I am asking for consistency as opposed to demanding things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** bash is *uniquely* the wrong tool for this job.

But, anyway:

- Bash functions don't have `return` in the way that you're trying to use it; the `return` statement sets the exit status. You should be using `echo` to produce output from the function.
- Your big math expression is not well formed; `expr` is a command and should be inside the backticks, with a space after it, so that it gets run.
- Stylistically, mixing `let`, `expr`, and `$(())` is very messy, as is nesting all of them within a single line. Prefer using just `$(())` for arithmetic expansion (it's the most standard and portable method) and prefer breaking up complex expressions into smaller ones.

**With fixes:**

```
function countofnumbers
{
    if [ "$1" -lt 10 ]
    then
        echo "$1"
    else
        z=$(($1 / 10))
        modded=$(($1 % 10))
        recursive_call=$(countofnumbers $z)
        result=$((modded + recursive_call))
    fi
    echo "$result"
}
z=15
countofnumbers "$z"
```